# How do you get error code from syncronous roUrlTransfer call

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have this piece of code that gets and parses JSON from an HTTPS url:

```
Function GetJson(sUrl As String) As dynamic
    if sUrl = invalid return invalid
    httpGet = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
    httpGet.SetURL(sUrl)
    httpGet.EnableEncodings(true)
    httpGet.RetainBodyOnError(true)
    sData = httpGet.GetToString()
    if sData = "" 
        print "ERROR: " + sUrl + " : " + httpGet.GetFailureReason()
    end if

    data = ParseJson(sData)
    return data
End Function
```

sData is empty.  How do I get the HTTP response code or error? `httpGet.GetFailureReason()` is always blank...

Turns out the fix was to add this, but I need to find out how to dump the the HTTP(s) error so I know what is going on

```
    httpGet.SetCertificatesFile("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt")
    httpGet.InitClientCertificates()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check documentation for [getToString](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifUrlTransfer#ifUrlTransfer-GetToString()asString). You can't get response code with synchronous call. Use asyncGetToString instead.

Comment: It is unfortunate indeed. You can however use `GetToFile()` which will return the HTTP response code, as a way to avoid dealing with async gallimaufry